# QTP/UFT - Collapse All Functions

Tags: vbscript, qtp, uft14

I have in my one *qfl* file about 14 functions that I call to my action. But generally when I open the solution file ever morning and navigate to the function file, all the functions are expanded again.

Then I need to click on every single function to collapse it - I do this because it helps navigate through the file quicker because there is now only one line of code for each function to scroll through instead of scrolling through every line inside the function ONLY to go past it.

Yes, I am aware that this doesn't even take a minute to do, but I am trying to be efficient and as a programmer in general, I'm just lazy and don't want to repeat this everyday.

I cannot seem to find a solution anywhere for this.

Is it possible to create a button or shortcut key that can do this?

If I have posted this in the wrong place, please advise where to post it. :)

Comment: There are two bars along the top of the `UFT` window.  The one on the right holds a list of functions along with their API for the current document.  Just navigate between functions from that list if you're feeling lazy.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for the reply. I see, I can use that yes. :) Would be great if the feature I mentioned above can actually be implemented though

Comment: so there is no option for this? :S